# iOS: how to convert nib-involving codes to storyboard codes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, storyboard

Recently I started learning iOS programming, and I found some books about iOS programming in Objective-C. The book (learning iOS programming, 2013) has a part which demonstrates the way to produce table-view apps, but I got stuck in some codes in the book.

For example, the book used below codes in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of AppDelegate.h to implement the desired table.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

City *london=[[City alloc] init];
london.cityName=@"London";
london.cityDescription=@"The capital of the United Kingdom and England.";
london.cityPicture=[UIImage imageNamed:@"London.jpg"];

City *sanFrancisco=[[City alloc] init];
sanFrancisco.cityName=@"San Francisco";
sanFrancisco.cityDescription=@"The heart of the San Francisco Bay Area.";
sanFrancisco.cityPicture=[UIImage imageNamed:@"SanFrancisco.jpg"];


City *sydney=[[City alloc] init];
sydney.cityName=@"Sydney";
sydney.cityDescription=@"The largest city in Australia.";
sydney.cityPicture=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sydney.jpg"];

City *madrid=[[City alloc] init];
madrid.cityName=@"Madrid";
madrid.cityDescription=@"The capital and largest city of Spain.";
madrid.cityPicture=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Madrid.jpg"];

self.cities=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:london,sanFrancisco,sydney,madrid, nil];

self.viewController=[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController=self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

/*UIStoryboard *test=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"        bundle:nil];
self.viewController=(UIViewController *) [test instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
self.window.rootViewController=self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];*/
return YES;

}
```

And the codes for AppDelegate.h is like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cities;


@end
```

So I followed the illustration in the book for the first time, but the app crashed and tells me that "could not load NIB in bundle". Then I check some similar problems here and know that NIB layout design is replaced by storyboard (I wrote some codes to try helping the problem but it didn't work, check the commented codes above). How to convert above codes to storyboard-compatible codes, especially the "initwithNibName",so that the same outcome will be produced? As I just have storyboard files for producing layouts(My Xcode is 8.3.3 and I cannot find any ways to implement nib files). Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `ViewController.xib` file or `Main.xib` file?

Comment: No, I see no xib file in my project. Just got viewcontroller.h and .m, main.storyboard/.m